# MonoDevelop Crashes silently

Tags: monodevelop

MonoDevelop crashes when opening any Solution. It doesn't print anything into the console even when setting `MONODEVELOP_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL=UpToError` or `MONODEVELOP_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL=error`. Does anyone else have this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to disable version control addin.
I found this answer [here](https://gitter.im/mono/monodevelop/).

Answer (score 3):

According to this [post](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/52939), MonoDevelop tries to get a specific library for git and crashes because it doesn't find it.
Here is the fix for Archlinux systems:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgit2.so /usr/lib/libgit2-e8b8948.so
```

Comment: This worked for me on ArchLinux. Don't forget to actually install [libgit2](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/libgit2/).